# What would the van der Waals parameters look like for gaseous metals?

Tags: gas-laws

So basically I'm trying to do some calculations on laser based machining, and it involved vaporizing a small mass from a target metal workpiece. I was assuming that a certain m mass of the metal vaporizes nearly instantaneously, and the resulting vapor expands from that initial volume.

I was using the van der Waals corrected gas equation, and wasn't sure how to quantify a and b for gaseous metals (take Al for example). I tried searching online, but couldn't find any values for gaseous metals.

Any help or resources I could refer to would be appreciated.

Comment: My first question would be why not treat it as an ideal gas and be done with it? The metal vapor is highly non-equilibrium to begin with, but will rapidly mix with the ambient and become dilute enough that any VdW parameters are irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to model, but the metal atoms will only be a gas for a fraction of second. As the hot gaseous metal diffuses into air it will probably oxidize and form  particulates.

Comment: @JonCuster I want the instantaneous pressure when the gas forms, because I'm using that to model the reaction force on the workpiece caused by the pressure exerted by the gas rapidly expanding. Mixing will indeed happen, but I'm attempting to see the part before that.

Comment: @MaxW Yeah I want to see the pressure during that fraction of a second for my model (since logically that should be the time when the pressure exerted by the gas is highest on the remainder of the workpiece)

Comment: Well, you get quite a nice shock wave just from rapidly heating a small surface volume with the laser without any vaporization, which complicates things further. That is a bigger effect than using VdW vs ideal gas parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the metal vapor oxidizing, the pressure of gas over your weld is unlikely to be much different from one atmosphere whereas [the critical pressure of almost everything is 10 atmospheres or (often a lot) more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)#Table_of_liquid%E2%80%93vapor_critical_temperature_and_pressure_for_selected_substances).  Generally gases become non-ideal when the pressure is a large fraction of the critical one; we are well below pressures where that occurs.  So the Ideal Gas Law works -- until the metal vapor oxidizes.

Comment: But wouldn't the instantaneous pressure of the gas be pretty high (Considering that it is in gaseous state, but within the volume of the solid state)? It will indeed expand rapidly and cause the pressure to equalize with the external environment, but I wanted the pressure at that instant of gas formation.